# How do I write a function that returns itself?

Tags: function, rust, return, return-type

What I want to make is a function, that returns itself, so I can call it like this:

```rust
foo()()...()
```

In C# it would be done via delegates:

```
delegate SelfFunc SelfFunc();

static void Main() {
    SelfFunc foo = null;
    foo = () => {
        return foo;
    };
    foo()()...();
}
```

Anticipating questions like "why implement such silly behavior?": I want to sum numbers in a very strange way using single function continues calls: `foo(1)(2)(3)()` = 6, but in this question I just want to know how to return function itself. Example realization of this method that I made in C#. This is all just for fun and to learn Rust:

```cs
static int sum = 0;
delegate dynamic InfFunc(int i = int.MaxValue);
 
static void InfFuncTest() {
    InfFunc f = null;
    f = (int i) => {
        if(i == int.MaxValue) {
            return sum;
        }
        sum += i;
        return f;
    };
 
    var g = f;
    var value = g(1)(2)(3)();
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: In `foo(1)(2)(3)() = 6` you seem to have a function which, depending on whether it's given 0 or 1 argument, returns a function or a number. A function in Rust can't have a variable number of argument so this exact syntax isn't possible.

Comment: BTW this kind of game is better suited to other SE sites, or forums, IMO.

Comment: While this can be done in (nightly) Rust, you probably shouldn't… Especially, closures have no ways of referring to themselves.

Comment: I'd go with `foo(1).then(2).then(3).finish()`. Much simpler, no magic needed. And the extra verbosity would make it easier for a future reader to understand what's happening.

Comment: @mcarton seems like you didn't quite understand me. The goal was exactly in creating over-complicated brainfuck realization that would work. Somehow, pushing something to it's limit is the finest way for me to comprehend it's abilities. If I wanted to sum numbers I could write simply `1 + 2 + 3`.

Comment: [Extremely inefficient and unergonomic but it works on stable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235172/97691). Disclaimer: I did write that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function that returns itself is possible on nightly.

First you need to enable the features `unboxed_closures` and `fn_traits`.

Then you can define a struct which, when called, returns `self`. The full code looks something like this:

```rust
#![feature(unboxed_closures, fn_traits)]

struct SelfFunc;

impl FnOnce<()>  for SelfFunc {
    type Output = SelfFunc;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _args: ()) -> Self::Output {
        self
    }
}
```

Then you can call the function as many times as you want:

```rust
fn main() {
  let f = SelfFunc;
  f()()()()()();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify how this can return a scalar, as in `foo(1)(2)(3)() = 6` ?

Comment: That's not possible in current rust, this is simply "a function which returns itself". You might want to take a look at "the builder pattern" in rust specifically

Comment: @cameron1024 thank you for answer, just what I wanted.
@DenysSéguret I accidentally found out that you can overload struct calling, so, apparently, [this code](https://pastebin.com/3SPmaijG) works (please excuse me for bad code, I just started learning Rust). Result is: `Adding 1 Adding 2 Adding 3 Finished adding Sum = 6`. However I don't know how to get rid of tuple argument in struct function to make it look like `foo(1)(2)(3)()`.

Comment: You can use a tuple with a single element to get rid of the extra argument: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=24d8830a29047891424ffbc036c95444)

Comment: @Jmb What sourcery is this? :) Will these features ever be stabilized? The result looks very much like Rust with function overloading, at least in part (by function arity).

Comment: @user4815162342 It's always been possible to [use traits with type parameters to get something like function overloading by type](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9d9557d87daf3b47f0f271967ae225e9) in Rust, but with the unstable `Fn` traits, it's also possible to get overloading by arity.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @cameron1024's answer, you can "overload" using traits, but you will need 2 structs to handle the empty case properly of `foo()` (here called `Add`) without any arguments returning `0`.

```rust
#![feature(unboxed_closures, fn_traits)]

struct Add;

impl FnOnce<(u32,)>  for Add {
    type Output = AddImpl;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (u32,)) -> Self::Output {
        AddImpl(args.0)
    }
}

impl FnOnce<()>  for Add {
    type Output = u32;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _args: ()) -> Self::Output {
        0
    }
}

struct AddImpl(u32);

impl FnOnce<()>  for AddImpl {
    type Output = u32;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _args: ()) -> Self::Output {
        self.0
    }
}

impl FnOnce<(u32,)>  for AddImpl {
    type Output = AddImpl;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (u32,)) -> Self::Output {
        Self(self.0 + args.0)
    }
}


fn main() {
    dbg!( Add(1)(2)(3)() );
    dbg!( Add() );
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c7861ebe23aac9951c130ae010b5b95)

If you do not care about the no-args `foo()` requirement, you can make `Add` a tuple struct instead and remove `AddImpl`:

```rust
#![feature(unboxed_closures, fn_traits)]

struct Add(u32);

impl FnOnce<(u32,)>  for Add {
    type Output = Add;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (u32,)) -> Self::Output {
        Add(self.0 + args.0)
    }
}

impl FnOnce<()>  for Add {
    type Output = u32;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _args: ()) -> Self::Output {
        self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    dbg!( Add(1)(2)(3)() );
    //dbg!( Add() ); // doesn't compile
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6bfa3cad17f46dc64a6530f3bd9076c3)

Although I should note that this likely isn't such a great idea, using an slice/iterator would likely result in cleaner code:

```rust
fn main() {
    dbg!([1, 2, 3].iter().copied().sum::<u32>());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d3a0cfdd5c306fe37553944994d71efb)